# How to empty my inbox and unfollow a question

Tags: support, notifications, follow-posts

How do I empty my inbox and unfollow a question?

Comment: This is actually a really good question. I see no reason why you shouldn't be able to empty it. Mine holds 1159 pages of some 20 messages per page, of old notifications that hold absolutely zero interest to anyone including myself. It's just one massive waste of space.

Comment: Furthermore, I suppose there might be GDPR:ish data among those messages so maybe SO _has_ to support a way to remove it, upon request?

Comment: Why did you make me think about this? Now I want to be able to empty it. I need that thing to be an inbox, not a bottomless paper bin!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inbox here?

[image]

Yeah, you can't empty that.  It keeps the last X messages indefinitely, from across the entire network.

To unfollow a question, click the "X" in your profile.

[image]

Comment: @m.rialfun Just for completeness' sake, if you're on the page for the actual question (instead of your profile page), you can also unfollow by clicking the link under the question that says 'Following'.  If you hover over it, there's a tooltip that says `Unfollow this question to stop receiving notifications`.  If you click on it, the text will change back to 'Follow', and you'll stop receiving notifications for activity on that question.  Of course it's much simpler to just do it from your profile :D

Comment: Also, just for completeness' sake, you cannot unfollow your own questions & answers.

Comment: Rather than "empty", perhaps OP would be satisfied with "mark as read"?

Comment: Also unfortunately you can't unfollow other users. Such as your persistent stalkers.